# File not being written to in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, streamwriter

I did some google searching and everyone gives me the same answer which isn't working. I hope its something simple I am missing. I am trying to test write a line to a txt file. The file was created just fine when I used  similar code, and no errors are thrown, the txt just doesn't write/save to the file. I am using stream writer in VB.
Here is my code:

```
   Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
Private Sub btnGen2DArray_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
Handles btnGen2DArray.Click
    Try

        'this is the file created and where it is saved:
        Dim fileLoc As String = "c:\Users\clint\save.txt"
        If File.Exists(fileLoc) Then
            Using sw As New StreamWriter(fileLoc)
                sw.Write("Test line write")
                sw.Close()
            End Using
        End If
        MsgBox("C++ 2D array text file created in: " + fileLoc, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Successful")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("error: " + e.ToString(), MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

I am using vb 2012 if this helps. Normal windows form application.

Comment: The solution is simple - don't use VS 2003. :)

Comment: Am now using VS 2012, same issue. :)

Comment: Do you get an error? Do you get the "C++ 2D array ..." pop-up?

Comment: Still no error, the msgbox pops up correctly.

Comment: Now that's weird! Usually upgrading to VS 2012 solves all sorts of problem. :) As a test, remove all irrelevant code, and just ALWAYS write some "test line" into the file, see if it works. It helps to reduce scope of the problem.

Comment: Ok, removed irrelevant code not yet used. Still nothing, put a test line in manually and ran the code. The result is the same successful message, and the original line is still there, no additions/changes to the file. Am I needing to open the file before writing or something simple like that? All the examples I see on the web are pretty much the same as mine. Will update question with "bare-bone" code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [close your StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close.aspx) when you are done. `sw.Close`

> You must call Close to ensure that all data is correctly written out
>   to the underlying stream.

Better yet, use [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx). The following would go inside your if:

```
Using sw As New StreamWriter(fileLoc)
    sw.Write("Test line write")
        For rowcount As Double = 1 To rows
            For colcount As Double = 1 To cols
                'when the file write test works I will finish the rest of the code here
            Next
        Next
End Using
```

This will automatically dispose of the StreamWriter for you.

Comment: Hey thanks Daniel for the quick reply, I tried the close method you first pointed out, and while there are still no errors, the file is still blank. I then tried the using method and got a "using not declared" error. I did some googling and everything says i need to use imports system.configuration, which I did and it still throws the error. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Right... Using requires > Visual Studio 2005 why are you using such old software?

Comment: That is the software I have currently, I have to believe there is a way to do this with this limitation. If I can't get this I might switch programming languages as the end result is all that matters to me. Though I would like to figure this out for the sake of figuring it out.

Comment: I presume you are using .NET Framework 1.1? As I do not have that Framework installed, perhaps this will be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w(v=vs.71).aspx Or possibly this http://stackoverflow.com/q/15443739/1316573 or this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287548(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Ok, upgraded to VS2012 (much better btw) edited changes into the question. Still have same problem using the "Using" block you requested, the file is still blank.

Comment: Hey Daniel, I got it to work with the Using statement after changing the \ to / in the path name. Should that have mattered? Thanks for the help.